# R: get last row of each group in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I need to get the last row of each group in a dataframe grouped by two columns.

I've tried some options seen in other posts but they're nor working for me.

This is my dataframe:

```
   Day        Date                  Status    Element
 1 2020-09-01 2020-09-01 07:00:00        0          A
 2 2020-09-01 2020-09-01 07:00:00        0          B
 3 2020-09-01 2020-09-01 07:00:00        1          C
 4 2020-09-01 2020-09-01 07:00:00        1          D
 5 2020-09-01 2020-09-01 08:00:00        0          E
```

It is grouped by `Day` and `Element`. I need the last row of each group when the column `Status` is 1.

I'm trying this:

```
output = df%>% 
      filter(status== 1) %>% 
      slice(n())
```

But I'm getting the error: `Error in UseMethod("slice") :  no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `dplyr` has a nice function for doing this.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    slice_tail(n = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working:

```
output = df %>% 
      filter(Status == 1) %>% 
      do(tail(., 1))
```